# AppCenter Test chunking failed:

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-test

I have a UITest that I would to use on AppCenter but I am getting this error message Test chunking failed.

```
\ Preparing tests... Test chunking failed: Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.

appcenter test run uitest --app "NCCN/Reimbursement-Android" --devices d1c9f63e --debug --app-path "PathToAPK.apk" --test-series "master" --locale "en_US" --build-dir "PathToReleaseFoler"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your problem is that the `--build-dir` has a lot of unnecessary files. Try to point that to a folder with just only the needed files, for example, in my case I have:

- [My own project dll/s]
- Xamarin.*
- nunit.framework.dll

Just those, and it works fine.